# How can I extract returned lastUpdatedTime field from the following N1QL query in Couchbase version 7.0.3 and use it in an update query

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I have the following query;

```
SELECT b.lastUpdatedTime
     FROM `bag` b WHERE b.staticBar='ABC1234511991' 
     ORDER BY b.lastUpdatedTime DESC LIMIT 1
```

Which returns the following response

```
[
  {
    "lastUpdatedTime": 1672840089805
  }
]
```

I would like to extract lastUpdatedTime field from the response array so that I can use that value in another query such as this;

```
UPDATE `bag` SET updated = true
WHERE staticBar='ABC1234511991'
  AND lastUpdatedTime IN 
  (
   SELECT lastUpdatedTime FROM `bag` AS bs 
   WHERE bs.staticBar='ABC1234511991' 
   ORDER BY bs.lastUpdatedTime DESC LIMIT 1
  )
```

Write now the update query does not apply any update although the there is a data available.

I tried to use UNNEST and MERGE syntax but failed to achieve my goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RAW in subquery so that it will generate ARRAY of values vs ARRAY of Objects.

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON bag(staticBar, lastUpdatedTime DESC);


UPDATE `bag` SET updated = true
WHERE staticBar='ABC1234511991'
  AND lastUpdatedTime IN 
  (
   SELECT RAW lastUpdatedTime FROM `bag` AS bs 
   WHERE bs.staticBar='ABC1234511991' 
   ORDER BY bs.lastUpdatedTime DESC LIMIT 1
  );
```

Above one not optimal because right side of IN is subquery, so not able to push the predicate to indexer. So use following merge statement

```
MERGE INTO bag AS m USING (SELECT b.lastUpdatedTime
                           FROM `bag` b 
                           WHERE b.staticBar='ABC1234511991'
                           ORDER BY b.lastUpdatedTime
                           DESC LIMIT 1) AS s
  ON s.lastUpdatedTime = m.lastUpdatedTime
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET m.updated = true;
```